# Convert a Java plug-in to PHP in eclipse

Tags: java, php, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plug-in that works in Java projects. How can I convert to make it work in PHP projects is as well? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plugin is an OSGi bundle and OSGi bundles usually don't care if the actual eclipse IDE is currently used to develop Java or PHP.

eclipse bundles may be designed to contribute to certain extension points so there's a chance, that your plugin contributes to JDT extension points which are not "visible" (bad word, hope you know what I mean) from the PHP development tools.

It may depend on some other bundles that are not available or have not been installed/started. Execute the platform with the `-command` option to get the OSGi command line interface and check the status of your plugins. (`help` shows available commands)

Comment: Good answer. I just have a command, when they invoke it to the menu I use the JDT API to create class, fields etc. is there a similar API for the PHP? can you shed a little bit more light on this?